# TypeError: $.ui is undefined in checkout

Tags: checkout, jquery, magento2.2.3

This is driving me mad! Something is mucking up the loading of `jQuery` and `jQueryui` in our `checkout` - we have tried everything we can find on the web - (we are using theme porto)
Their support is almost useless - as when they looked it was fine on one persons computer, so they wasted 3 days ignoring us.
Does anyone have an idea - how i can identify which `3rd party script` is the problem? The site is live and in production so i cannot simply take it apart- it seems to work for most people, but when it goes wrong - nothing ic an do can get it to work - `clearing caches` etc
So any ideas would be hugely appreciated

you can see from the image that i tested for jQuery loading

we are using **magento 2.2.3**

[image]